# LIFERAY 6.2 - How to specify a another Portlet at renderURL

Tags: url, liferay, portlet

I'm having difficulty to work with "renderURL". I created a new portlet, let's call it of "Portlet A", and one of my pages (wich is a simple CRUD), When I test acessing directly my Portlet It works perfectly.

The problem is that I trying to use my page, acessing It by another Portlet, let's call it of "Portlet B", and here's the complication because When I click at the button "save", instead of the system search for my method save() at the class MVCPortlet of Portlet A, It searchs at the class MVCPortlet of Portlet B.

Now at Portlet B, I call my page of Portlet A using "renderURL", like this:

```html
<portlet:renderURL var="editInboxURL" >
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/gerenciarinbox/search.jsp" />
    <portlet:param name="eventoId" value="<%= eventoId %>"/>
    <portlet:param name="redirect" value="%=themeDisplay.getURLCurrent()%>"/>
</portlet:renderURL>
```

and I access like this:

```html
<aui:button  value="Go to Portlet A" onClick="${editInboxURL}" />
```

I was wondering if There's somehow at the renderURL I specify that I don't want just to call my page, but I want to go to the "Portlet A" too.
I want to go the that specific page (search.jsp) and to the Portlet that It's belongs (Portlet A).

Can someone helps me?

I saw there's a way to work with "portlet:renderURL" addind a portletName, but I tryied and It didn't worked, It just stayed at the same page, nothing happened.

```html
<liferay-portlet:renderURL portletName="gopointseventos_WAR_gopointseventosportlet" var="editInboxURL" >
<portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/gerenciarinbox/search.jsp" />
<portlet:param name="eventoId" value="<%= eventoId %>"/>
<portlet:param name="redirect" value="<%= themeDisplay.getURLCurrent()%>"/>
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As per understanding, you want to create a render URL of PortletA from PortletB.
Please give it try from below code snippet.

```
LiferayPortletURL anotherPortletURL = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(request,portletName, 
plid, PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);
```

where `plid` can be retrieved from below code.

```
  long plid= PortalUtil.getPlidFromPortletId(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(),isPrivateLayout, portletId);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: a portlet is **not** a folder with some JSPs inside. A portlet can call any jsp inside its plugin (and a plugin can contain any number of portlets).

So your search.jsp it **not** belongs to Portlet B.

When in your Portlet A you call the search.jsp it is normal that the active portlet will always be the Portlet A.

Easiest way to achieve what you need is to copy the action method called by the save button in MVCPortlet of Portlet A.